# Windows Virtual PC

Tags: windows, virtualization, desktop

Does anyone know when Microsoft is coming out with a newer version of Windows Virutal PC where it supports 64bit guess.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't hold your breath, I'm pretty sure MS doesn't give a hoot about that in any way, it's a legacy product as far as they see it.